How to make Junit 5 pause other threads and execute just one specfic test class
I expected adding @Execution(ExecutionMode.SAME_THREAD) to work but it doesn't. Other tests run in parallel. Is there some annotation to synchronize test threads and make them actually wait?
As an example I would expect all other tests hold until AaInitialStateITCase is finished. But it doesn't it runs dummies in parallel.
So basically I want some tests to be executed alone, especially initialization.

This is what actually happens with forkCount = 4:

Running pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy2ITCase
Running pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy1ITCase
Running pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.AaInitialStateITCase
Running pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy3ITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 27.68 s -- in pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy1ITCase
Running pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy4ITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 s -- in pl.mol.molnet.initsaas.Dummy4ITCase

Example ITCase
/**
 * Init main database objects.
 * @author Maciej Nux Jaros
 */
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/testContextPg.xml"})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Execution(ExecutionMode.SAME_THREAD)   // cannot be run in paralel
public class AaInitialStateITCase extends TestDatabaseCleaner {
    @BeforeAll
    public void mockTenantService() throws SaasException {
        initAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInit_shouldInitTenants() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(tenant1);
        assertNotNull(tenant2);
    }
}

/**
 * Artificial test exhausting threads.
 * @author Maciej Nux Jaros
 */
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/testContextPg.xml"})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Dummy1ITCase extends TestDatabaseCleaner {
    @Test
    public void test_forthreads() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(2, 1+1);
    }
}

Maven config:
            <!-- ITCase setup -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire-failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                    <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1280m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = same_thread
                            # class order to init DB safely
                            junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default = org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$ClassName
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


How do you run your tests? Some tools add their own parallelization on top of what JUnit is doing.

@johanneslink added maven config (running with failsafe as those are itcases)

If you are using Junit5, consider adding @Isolated annotation on the test class. It ensures that the class runs in isolation and no other class is running at the same time.
@Isolated
public class myTestClass{
}

This is per the official Junit 5 Documentation:

If most of your test classes can be run in parallel without any
synchronization but you have some test classes that need to run in
isolation, you can mark the latter with the @Isolated annotation.
Tests in such classes are executed sequentially without any other
tests running at the same time.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/
